# Installing Ubuntu 20.04.02 Live ISO on Windows 2019 Hyper-V

Tags: 20.04, hyper-v

I have several Ubuntu servers running on my Windows 2019 Hyper-V however I lost the ISO image.  I downloaded `ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso` and when I create a new VM it bombs every time:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I have:

- Windows 2019 Server w/24 Cores, 256 GB of RAM, and 4 TB of usable space.
- Generation 2, Secure Boot unchecked
- 32 GB of RAM
- 12 Virtual Processors
- 1 TB of hard disk space (tried 25 GB, 125 GB, and 512 GB)
- SCSI Controller
- All but Guest Services checked.

I must have forgotten a step.  Any ideas?

Comment: The installer fails at:

finish: cmd-install/stage-curthooks/001-configure-apt/cmd-in-target: FAIL: curtin command in-target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - I found the source of the issue. The connection to internet goes through a firewall with ssl inspection enabled and therefore the repository can't be accessed.
I disabled the nic during install and the os setup completes. Since I don't manage the firewall I wasn't able to test with SSL inspection disabled.

BR,
Marc

Comment: That fixed it!  I unplugged my system from the network and install worked as expected!  Your a super genius.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same error. I tried Ubuntu 18.04, gen1 vm, gen2 vm, tried using hwe kernel. I wonder if it is related to underlying (host) hardware or BIOS/firmware updates. Or the latest Windows updates of the host.

Comment: Turns out it's IPv6 is causing the issue.   My DHCP server has that turned off and Ubuntu install fails with there is garbage for that.   IPv4 works perfect